# Ajax post value isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have here dropdown and combobox. I tried to post the value using ajax. My ajax below works if I create another dropdown but when I changed and connect it in combobox the ajax doesn't working.

Why ajax doesn't working? Help please

I also got an error in console in dhtmlxcombo.js:11 it says TypeError: is a null

And here's the line 11

```
"keydown",function(a){try{(a||event).keyCode==9&&window.dhx_glbSelectAr[0].closeAll()}catch(b){}return!0});if(a.tagName=="SELECT")return dhtmlXComboFromSelect(a);else this._createSelf(a,b,c,d);dhx_glbSelectAr.push(this)}dhtmlXCombo.prototype.setSize=function(a){this.DOMlist.style.width=a+"px";if(this.DOMlistF)this.DOMlistF.style.width=a+"px";this.DOMelem.style.width=a+"px";this.DOMelem_input.style.width=Math.max(0,a-19)+"px"};
```

Ajax.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
<script>
window.dhx_globalImgPath = "combobox/imgs/";
</script>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="combobox/dhtmlxcombo.css">
<script  src="combobox/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
<script  src="combobox/dhtmlxcombo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
 Drop1
 <?php
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
     while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>

<select id="main" name="main">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
<select style='width:200px;'  id="combo_zone1" name="alfa1">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<div id="combo_zone2" style="width:200px; height:30px;"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<script>
var z = dhtmlXComboFromSelect("combo_zone1");
var z = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone2", "alfa2", 200);
z.readonly(1);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#main').change(function(){
$.ajax({
url : 'getajax.php',
data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
$('#combo_zone1').html(data);
}
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Getajax.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["mainlist_id"])) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mainlist_id"]);


$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE cat_code='$main' GROUP BY item_code ORDER BY item");

    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $row['item_code'];?>"><?php echo $row['item'];?></option>';
<?php
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try to change this line -> `data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},` to `data :{'mainlist_id' : $(this).val()},` and then check the console. It seems error because `mainlist_id` is not defined

Comment: `mainlist_id` is a key from an object defined on the fly, it's not an error.

Comment: @AldiUnanto doesn't work. And in console no error

Comment: I think `mainlist_id` is difference with `'mainlist_id'`, the first is variable and the second is string. AJAX Post, we should send a string, except that variable has a value.

Comment: @user3318208 check whether the AJAX return a value or not. I usually do with `alert(data)` on `success: function(){}`

Comment: @AldiUnanto I get the value what I need in alert. But why isn't go to my combobox?

Comment: I also got an error in console in dhtmlxcombo.js:11 it says TypeError: is a null

Comment: There is a `..</option>';` on your getajax.php file. Delete the `';` from the end (in the loop).

Comment: @vlzvl still doesn't work

Comment: If you get correct `data` from GetAjax.php (etc. the `<option>`s string) in your `:success` callback, i dont see a reason not to get a populated selection box. Are you getting the `<option>`s string? What your `alert(data);` or `console.log(data);` says?

Comment: I think this error was in combobox script -_- Can you gave me a link how to create a simple combobox?